# If string is equal to regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

Is there any way to check if a string is exactly equal to a regular expression in Python? For example, if the regex is `\d\s\d`, it should allow strings `1 5`, `8 2`, etc, but not `lorem 9 4 ipsum` or `a7 3`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strings and regex are different types. I think you're looking to check not whether a string is "exactly equal to" a regex, but that the regex matches the entire string. To do that, just use [start and end anchors  (`^` and `$`, respectively)](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) in the regex. For example:

```
^\d\s\d$
```

instead of

```
\d\s\d
```

Comment: Also worth noting that `re.match()` only looks at the start of the string, whereas `re.search()` searches the whole string.